# Bootstrap 3 set position relative for rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it ok if I set .row{position: relative} in bootstrap 3.2?

It helps do some resizing in columns but I don't know if it is going to make any problems in the future. Has anyone any experience on this?

Thank you.

Comment: That is okay. Was it?

Comment: well not until now but i don't if it is going to create issues. The project is in its initial steps and I don't know if it going to break any new component that i will need to install. Maybe there is a reason why the have left it static.